# Bulk Log Database query T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, backup

What is the query to bulk log backup a database 
I have the following for SIMPLE AND FULL, is it something similar to this?

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [database name] SET RECOVERY FULL
GO
exec [dbo].[up_DBA_Create_Jobs_op] [database name]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the database recovery model to bulk logged with the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE [database name] SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple recovery model works with the full or differential database backup. There is no opportunity to apply the transaction log backup.

```
ALTER DATABASE [database name] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
```

The full recovery model works with a full, differential and transaction log backups. The full recovery model allows a point-in-time recovery.

```
ALTER DATABASE [database name] SET RECOVERY FULL
```

The bulk-logged recovery model almost the same as the full recovery model if no minimally logged transactions are created in the database.

```
ALTER DATABASE [database name] SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED
```